# iOS POST to Google Froms (Spreadsheet)

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, http, google-docs

I am trying to set up a very simple app, that takes in a number from an input field, and then POSTS using an `NSMutableURLRequest` to a Google Spreadsheet, using the action URL from the Google Form.

So far I have a simple text box and button, and this code. The field name I am using is: 
`name="entry.931001663"`

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *inputField;
- (IBAction)submit:(id)sender;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
  [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
  // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
} 

- (IBAction)submit:(id)sender {

NSString *bodyData = self.inputField.text;
NSLog(@"Input = %@", bodyData);
NSMutableURLRequest *postRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1rGpFfI2ebyn_SbuDVVUg7Q4yuvKzd3RRXb0vRxeIDxc/formResponse"]];
[postRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[postRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[postRequest setHTTPBody:[NSData dataWithBytes:[bodyData UTF8String] length:strlen([bodyData UTF8String])]];



}
@end
```

Comment: What problem you are facing, explain?

Comment: It just not working. Not posting. I have it posting using the URL: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1rGpFfI2ebyn_SbuDVVUg7Q4yuvKzd3RRXb0vRxeIDxc/formResponse?entry_931001663=value if I use the Dev HTTP Client. But can't get the app to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about the error, but [Google's Sample Code](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/source/browse/#svn/trunk/Examples/SpreadsheetSample) can help you. You can also use [GData Objective C Client](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/) to use it.